# Geodist with where or match

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx, sphinxql, manticore-search

I need combine this 2 query in one, and sort by Id,

```
select GEODIST(40, 50, latitude,longitude, {in=degrees, out=meters}) AS distance, id FROM offersRT WHERE distance<=1000 LIMIT 0,30;
```

and

```
select 0 as distance, id FROM offersRT WHERE MATCH('@location_path_id 39644') LIMIT 0,30;
```

I use Manticore 3.6.0.

I can't use OR statement like

```
WHERE distance<=1000 or MATCH('@location_path_id 39644')
```

i also try like this:

```
SELECT id FROM (
      select 0 as distance, id FROM offersRT WHERE MATCH('@location_path_id 39644') LIMIT 0,30;
      select GEODIST(40, 50, latitude,longitude, {in=degrees, out=meters}) AS distance, id FROM offersRT WHERE distance<=1000 LIMIT 0,30;
);
```

and not working too.

Is there any other option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well it MATCH('@location_path_id 39644') doesnt really need to use the 'keywords' index. Its not a really a keyword match, and something that can easily be done with an attribute filter. Ie can just make `location_path_id` an **attribute**.

Manticore at least should then support OR directly in the WHERE (it just doesn't with MATCH)

```
SELECT GEODIST(40, 50, latitude,longitude, {in=degrees, out=meters}) AS distance, id 
FROM offersRT WHERE distance<=1000 OR location_path_id = 39644 LIMIT 0,30;
```

But if that doesn't work, can definitely implement the 'OR' in the SELECT section

```
SELECT GEODIST(40, 50, latitude,longitude, {in=degrees, out=meters})<=100 + location_path_id = 39644 AS filter, id 
FROM offersRT WHERE filter > 0 LIMIT 0,30;
```

The second form should work even in Sphinx.

Comment: MATCH('@location_path_id 39644') must be a keywords index because they constants multiple id like "39644 123 983 23234" etc. Search by attribute require albo full index scan.

I don't find a solutions so I refactored all code to use just one query with match location_path_id.

Comment: Multiple values like that could go in the special Multi Value Attribute (MVA) type. it specifically for holding multiple ids.